# DataTable.js - No data displays within <tbody></tbody> for certain DataSets coming in via Ajax calls

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

For certain datasets no data is displayed within the DataTable  - only Column Headers or Column labels are displayed . This happens even though there is no change in code on the page . Data in question is correctly displayed within browser devtools Console.logs.

JSON as seen below for DataSet that displays / renders correctly on the HTML page.

```
{"data_json": 

{"columns": ["customer_id", "col_1_int", "col_2_int", "col_3_float", "col_4_int", "col_5_str"], 

"data": 
[[1, "349", "349", "355.6677", "112", "hello am a string "],
 [2, "404", "404", "355.6677", "167", "hello am a string "], 
 [3, "459", "459", "355.6677", "222", "hello am a string "],
```

JSON as seen below for DataSet that doesnt display correctly on the HTML page.

```
{"data_json": 

{"columns": ["rats_mice", "var_rats1", "var_rats2"], 

"data": 
[["CAT_C", 6.0, 69.0], 
["CAT_A", 3.0, 34.0], 
["CAT_B", 4.0, 37.0], 
["CAT_B", 5.0, 63.0], 
["CAT_C", 5.5, 88.0],
```

The JS code for the DataTables as seen below :-

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
</table>

<script>
        var myUrl = "{% url 'django_url_withJSON' %}" 
        var dataSet;
        var my_columns = []; 

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                    url: myUrl,
                    type: 'GET',     
                    dataType: 'json', 
                    success: function(dict_json_from_py) {
                      console.log("-----dict_json_from_py--Data displays fine in Console--")
                      console.log(dict_json_from_py)
                      var dataSet = dict_json_from_py.data_json.columns;
                      //console.log(dataSet)
                      $.each(dataSet, function( key, value ) {
                                                var my_item = {};
                                                my_item.data = key; 
                                                my_item.title = value;
                                                console.log(my_item.data)
                                                console.log(my_item.title)
                                                my_columns.push(my_item); 
                                                console.log(my_columns)
                                                return my_columns
                                        });

                        assignToEventsColumns(my_columns,dict_json_from_py);
                    }, // Close - success:
                })    // Close - "ajax":

            function assignToEventsColumns(my_columns,dict_json_from_py) {

                    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                        "bAutoWidth" : false, //bAutoWidth -- b == BOOLEAN
                        "serverSide": false, // 
                        "aaData": dict_json_from_py.data_json.data, 
                        "columns" : my_columns,
                      })
                  }
              }); 

    </script>
```

Beyond checking for consistency in the JSON structure - am not sure what else can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked your code, seems fine to me. just make sure that you have JSON in the correct format. Hope this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sandeepk7/s1hg8rjn/5/) will help you.

```
{
  "data_json": {
    "columns": [
      "customer_id", "col_1_int", "col_2_int", "col_3_float", "col_4_int", "col_5_str"
      ],
    "data":
    [
      [1, "349", "349", "355.6677", "112", "hello am a string "],
      [2, "404", "404", "355.6677", "167", "hello am a string "],
      [3, "459", "459", "355.6677", "222", "hello am a string "]
   ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ Sandeep - this solves my issue , have accepted your answer - thanks .

Comment: The issue seems to be because of JS and CSS versions and not the JSON Format as i had thought earlier. I have created a Fiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/RohitDhankar/2pxndLe4/31/ and also hosted my two JSON Formats on Github -- https://github.com/RohitDhankar/test_json_foo. Both these formats render absolutely OK on JSFiddle . The issue still persists on my local dev environment - im still checking and will post an update.

Comment: Yes confirmed issue existed as i had multiple instances of minified JS files both being served locally by Django and coming in from CDN , but still need to understand why certain datasets were being rendered as DataTables and others not - as the JSON format was never changed by me .